# How to switch accounts in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to build react native app in which user will have option to switch multiple accounts, similar to Instagram. My problem is, How to change user data on when user switches account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `react-native-keychain` to store the `Active User` and `User List`. This will store the data in `Device`.

```
const StoreData = async () => {
   let activeUser = 'User1'
   let userList = [
      { ID: 'User1' },
      { ID: 'User2' }
   ]
   userList = JSON.stringify(userList)
   await Keychain.setGenericPassword(activeUser, userList); // Note: activeUser and userList should be string.
}
```

```
const RetrieveData = async () => {
   try {
      const credentials = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
      if (!credentials)
         return console.log('No credentials stored')
      
      let { username: activeUser, password: userList } = credentials
      userList = JSON.parse(userList)
      return console.log({ activeUser, userList })
    } catch (error) {
        return console.log("Keychain couldn't be accessed!", error);
    }
}
```

If you are using library similar to `Redux`, `MobX`, ... You can use them to refresh the `APP` with the selected user.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by having the token of the other users and then retrieve all the user data everytime you switch users.